# How to implement pagination on frontend in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, pagination

I have made cricket web app using ReactJS, NodeJS, MongoDB. On frontend I am displaying data from JSON objects per page I want to display 16 JSON objects. I am using `.slice(0,16)` method to slice JSON objects from REST API which returns 577 objects. Now how can I implement pagination for page 2,3,4,5.

For page 2 -> slice(17,33)
For page 3 -> slice(34,49)
and so on...

Below is my code and screenshot of my webapp:

in content.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './content.css';

class Content extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            matches:[],
            loading:true
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('api/matches')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.setState({
        matches:res.slice(0,16),
        loading:false
      })
    })
    }

    renderMatches() {
        return this.state.matches.map(match => {
            return (
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div id="content">
                        <p class="match">MATCH {match.id}</p>
                        <h4>{match.team1}</h4>
                        <p>VS</p>
                        <h4>{match.team2}</h4>
                        <div class="winner">
                            <h3>WINNER</h3>
                            <h4>{match.winner}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="stats">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">View Stats</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        })
    }

    render() {

        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <div>>Loading...</div>
        }

    return (
      <div>
          <div class="row">
            {this.renderMatches()}
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Content;
```

In Pagination.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Pagination extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <div class="container">
              <h2>Pagination</h2>
              <p>The .pagination class provides pagination links:</p>                  
              <ul class="pagination">
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Pagination;
```

Screenshot for more clarity :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj7QJ.png)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about store all the matches in the component state and only slice during rendering, based on the `page` query string?

In `componentDidMount()`, after fetching the data, simply set the state with all the matches:

```
  this.setState({
    matches: res,
  })
```

Then, given you want to control the pagination with a query string in the url, like:

```
?page=2
```

You can filter the matches in **render(**):

```
const RECORDS_PER_PAGE = 16;
const page = parseInt(getPageNumber(), 10) || 1; // defaults to 1 if no page query specified
const offset = (page - 1) * RECORDS_PER_PAGE

// do your mapping (do this in your renderMapping() method)
const matchComponents = this.state.matches.slice(0 + offset, RECORDS_PER_PAGE + offset).map(/* ... */);
```

where `getPageNumber()` is a method that gives you the query string value for page:

```
// Use your own query string parser if you wish
getPageNumber() {
  return window.location.search // <-- gives you access to the query parameters
  .slice(1) // remove the `?`
  .split("&")
  .reduce((queryHash, queryParam) => {

    // e.g. ?page=3 becomes ["page", "3"]
    const query = queryParam.split('=');
    return Object.assign({}, queryHash, ({
      [query[0]]: query[1] || null
    }));

  }, {}).page;
}
```